# How to change app name in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I am published one app in store in windows phone.now I want to change my   published  app name.how to change app name,please help me.how to change app name.

my app name is `xyz.in` 
Actually My package name is `xyz.in.xyz.in`
my package display name is  `xyz.in`

now i am changed package display name is `abc.in.` 
but what happend is whenever I am creating package,after successfully created package the `abc.in` is changed again `xyz.in`.what should I do.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Package.appxmanifest` file under the `Packaging` tab, change the field `Package display name`.

You can also have a localized app name by specifying `ms-resource:AppDisplayName` as the package display name, but then your `.resw` files need to have a string with the key `AppDisplayName` and of course you need to reserve the localized app names in your development dashboard on `dev.windows.com`.

Comment: then it will be created as new app or appended the name to that older app.i want to change the name of the app only

Comment: i want to change app name in store.

Comment: I am changed package display  name  and published in store.but no change app name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reserve a new name for your app in windows store. Check this link [Changing your published app display name](http://blogs.technet.com/b/adventuresinappdev/archive/2012/11/19/changing-your-published-windows-store-app-name.aspx). It shows step by step.

Answer (score 0):

**Step One:**
Reserve your app name in the Windows Store (like @Rohit said). [Instructions here.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/adventuresinappdev/archive/2012/11/19/changing-your-published-windows-store-app-name.aspx)

**Step Two:**
In Visual Studio (2015) go to Solution Explorer, select your solution, expand Properties, open WMAppManifest.xml, select the Application UI tab, enter the new name in the **Display Name** field.
[Instructions here.](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/beginner/how-to-change-the-app-name-and-tile-name-of-your-windows-phone-app-2/)